How to setValue to a form control without triggering validation
I'm modifying a control value inside a custom validator and I need to not fire validation because of the obvious problem of loop validation.
@Directive({
  selector: '[myValidator]',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: MyValidatorDirective,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class MyValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return myValidatorFn(
      this.phoneNumberValidationService,
      this.countryCodeControl,
      this.defaultCountryCode
    )(control);
  }
}


export function myValidatorFn(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (control.value) {
      if (control.value.indexOf("something") > 0) {
        return { myError: { value: true } };
      }
      control.setValue(control.value.replace("other", ""));// Some random value change, here is when the validation is called again
    }
    return null;
  };
}


I ended changing the setValue line for this code (I remove all validators, set the value, and add it again):
  const validatorFn = this.validator;
  if (validatorFn != null) {
    this.clearValidators();
  }
  this.setValue(value, options);
  if (validatorFn != null) {
    this.addValidators(validatorFn);
  }

